# Class not found laravel 8 only on production

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Hello I'm new to Laravel and Eloquent, all I found about this problems it that it can by Case sensitivity problems but I can't find any case problems.

:[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4W0cI.png)

`Class "App\Models\TvEpisode" not found`

I'm trying to get UserTvEpisode list to view it works fine in localhost (using Windows), but not on production server in throws an error that the class TvEpisode is not found.

User has many UserTvEpisode 's .
TvEpisode has many UserTvEpisode 's .

Filenames: TvEpisode.php , UserTvEpisode.php, TvEpisodeController.php

Controller that tries to get list:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\UserTvEpisode;
use App\Models\TvEpisode;
use Auth;

class TvEpisodeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $user = Auth::user();    
       
        $allTvEpisodes = UserTvEpisode::with('TvEpisode')->where("user_id", "=",  $user->id)->get();
        
        return view('tvepisode.index',[
            'allTvEpisodes' => $allTvEpisodes
        ]);
    }
}
```

UserTvEpisode model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Models\TvEpisode;

class UserTvEpisode extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'user_tv_episodes';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    public $timestamps = true;

    protected $dataFormate ='h:m:s';

    public function TvEpisode(){
        return $this->belongsTo(TvEpisode::class)->withDefault();;
    }
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

}
```

TvEpisode model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Models\UserTvEpisode;

class TvEpisode extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'tv_episodes';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $dataFormate ='h:m:s';

    public function userTvEpisodes(){
        return $this->hasMany(UserTvEpisode::class);
    }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Somewhat unrelated, but is this a typo: `dataFormate`, is it supposed to be `dateFormat`?

Comment: What class is not found? Paste the error into the question please. Otherwise, run `php artisan cache:clear` to see if it fixes things.

Comment: A common culprit is filename case. In windows filenames are case insensitive but if you deployed to a Linux server, where filenames are case sensitive, the filename must match the class name exactly e.g. it must be `TvEpisode.php`

Comment: Yes `dataFormat` was typo, did not fix  it. Tried running `php artisan cache:clear` did not help. Yes my files are named correct `TvEpisode.php`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are sure that there are no case sensitivity problems, you could try a couple of things:

1. Check if the namespaces of your classes are correct. Do the classes exists in the right directory, models in `App\Models` and the controller in `App\Http\Controllers`? If not, move the class or change the namespace.
2. Are you sure the file exists on the server? Is the project on the server up-to-date with your local project?
3. Run `composer dump-autoload` on the server to regenerate list of classes used in the project.

I am pretty sure one of the solution above will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for advise runing `composer dump-autoload` on heroku server showed an error: `Class App\Models\TvEpisode located in ./app/Models/Tvepisode.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.` I had same file before named with lower case and github ignored the change on file so it was pushing as `Tvepisode` not `TvEpisode`. Had to find this command to fix it  `git mv -f Tvepisode.php TvEpisode.php` , now it works Thanks You!

Answer (score 1):

The reason can be with `OPCache` (if you use it on production) and you just uploaded new files to a server and new PHP classes not indexed yet, so `composer dump-autoload` will not help you. You have to restart your php service to reindex all PHP instances in `OPCache` (this example for Ubuntu and Nginx with php 8.1 fpm):

```
sudo service php8.1-fpm restart
```

Also to make sure - restart your web server (for example nginx)

```
sudo service nginx restart
```